# IE8 won't display webpages unless ip address is given

Tags: dns, internet-explorer-8, connection

After installing IE8 I could no longer browse to a webpage using its URL.  If I enter the ip address then it connects.  Also, I can't send/receive email via Outlook, which seems to be a related problem since it uses URLs for the mail servers.

I have tried many fixes, including: disabling firewall, running winsock_xpfix, setting an alternate DNS address, and reinstalling IE8.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a DNS issue to me. Try this command:

nslookup www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

How certain are you that it's IE8's fault?  Did you perhaps also "manipulate" any services around the same time, such as, for example, the DNS Client service or TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper Service?  (The TCP/IP NetBIOS is ruled out if you are able to access other machines in your local network by their computer name.)